# HTTP requests to GoDaddy Servers from Android App times out intermittently

Tags: java, php, android, http, timeout

My Android App post HTTP requests to PHPs on Godaddy servers on shared economy hosting on Linux. The requests look like http://example.com/abc.php?user=abc@xyz.com

Until last night everything worked perfect for 2 months for 560 users using the App concurrently. From around 10.30pm last night we started getting Force Close in the App.

I started debugging it and found that the http posts to Godaddy servers return a response "Your Request has timed out" intermittently and that is why the App Force closes since the App expects the JSON response.

I called tech support at Godaddy and they told me that everything looks fine with the database and the servers on which we are hosted.

I am so lost and don't know how I can fix this time out issue. Any help or clue as to why this would happen all of a sudden is much appreciated.

NOTE: I wanted to add that absolutely nothing has changed in the Android App and PHPs in the version that we went live with in the last month.

Thanks.

Comment: set up some sort of retry method which would retry the request up to `MAX` times.  you should also validate the response you get back to the app doesn't display the force-close option when it times out or gives an error string

Comment: Random instability is pretty much par for the course on GoDaddy hosting. I've had support tickets lay fallow for months. Never again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem with Godaddy Servers and I worked around it with a fix in Android itself so that the response is first checked if it is 200 OK. If it is, go forward with further processing otherwise display dialog etc... depending on what the needs are. Atleast no force close in App around bad HTTP response from server.

Comment: hi Akash , can you answer the following question ?https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/fd77w8/what_are_the_best_hosting_options_for_my/

Comment: @AdarshGumashta answered on reddit.

Answer (score 0):

im getting this too on my app. tried changing the buffer in the php script as advised by the godaddy techs still not fixed. only started happening when my app database reached 500 + users. i call poll_server(); routine upon activity launch and thats where my timeout occurs.  If i click a button which calls the same routine there is no problem.  My Solution was to create a thread which waited one second and executed said routine.. pretty shit if u ask me seems asthough godaddy is dud.